# JS getElementById with empty string: Invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: javascript, string, getelementbyid, invalid-argument

I have a function, which has a parameter `sCellId` passed in. I'm trying to get its element using

```
var tdElement = document.getElementById(sCellId)
```

Now I have a null check after it, and I fully expect it to be `null` sometimes, which is fine (`if (tdElement)`). However, it seems that when an empty string is passed in, I get an exception instead:

> Invalid procedure call or argument.

In the watch, if I add `document.getElementById("")`, it works fine and gives me `null`. Adding `sCellId` to the watch I get an empty string `""`, and If I add `document.getElementById(sCellId)` to the watch, it again shows the error.

Here's a snapshot of the watched variables:

[image]

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: "Invalid procedure call or argument" does not sound like a common JavaScript exception. In what browser are you testing?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, but this is in IE9

Comment: Every browser I tested returns `null` if `id` is an undefined variable, even IE 6. Try testing `var x; alert(document.getElementById(x));`

Comment: Agreed, I can't get `getElementById` to return anything other than a node or `null`, regardless of what I pass in.

Comment: Can you show the function entire or provide the URL?

Comment: @AlexK. That statement is literally the first line in the function, so really the rest of it wouldn't help any.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this, it's just simply null in IE9. Can you reproduce it, and show us a "working" example? for example on jsfiddle.net . The only thing I can think of is that the variable you are trying to use is not yet defined, but it would throw a different error.

Comment: Aye but what you have pasted is at odds with what should happen & is not reproducible, so "something else" must be the cause

Comment: @Jason Hu I have this exact same issue.  Were you ever able to find out how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact issue, and it seems to be a bug in IE that only occurs **when in compatibility mode using IE7 or IE8 standards**. I was able to reproduce in IE 9 and IE 11 using the test HTML page below.  If I do not enable compat mode, then the page loads without any errors.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function runTest(ElementId) {
            document.getElementById(ElementId);
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            var fieldID = document.getElementById('TestHiddenField').value;

            //DEBUG OTUPUT: you can un-comment this for more detailed output
            //console.info("fieldId value: \"" + fieldID + "\""); //outputs: ""
            //console.info("typeof(fieldId): " + typeof (fieldID)); //shows correctly as string
            //console.info('fieldId.length: ' + fieldID.length); //0 length, so empty string.
            //if (fieldID == "") {
            //    console.info("fieldId value matches to empty string");
            //}

            runTest(fieldID); //SCRIPT5: Invalid procedure call or argument
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    This is a test.
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="TestHiddenField" />
</body>
</html>
```

Even though all of the debugging output above shows that the variable `fieldID` is set to an empty string at runtime, the (compat mode) fix involves changing this line:

```
var fieldID = document.getElementById('TestHiddenField').value;
```

Appending an empty string to hidden field value seems to fix the error:

```
var fieldID = document.getElementById('TestHiddenField').value + '';
```

Oddly, if you change it to use the `.toString()` function, then it does not work, and you still get the error:

```
var fieldID = document.getElementById('TestHiddenField').value.toString();
```